# How does distances weighting work in KNN?

Tags: r, knn

I'm writing KNN classifier in R. I want to add weighting scheme, e. g. inverted indices 1/d.  As it is, for Iris dataset I get almost perfect 66% accuracy (no matter the metric used) since value no. 3 ("virginica") almost never shows up and I want to make it better with weighting. My question is: what exactly and how do I weight? I've read that I should weight classes of K nearest neighbours with those distances.

I've tried creating vectors of classes and distances to K nearest neighbours and then taking weighted mean from it:

```
inverted <- function(vals, distances)
{
  inv_distances <- 1 / distances
  # eliminate division-by-zero errors
  inv_distances <- ifelse((inv_distances < 0.01), 0.01, inv_distances)

  weighted.mean(vals, inv_distances)
}
```

My results are weird: for correct vectors vals (classes) and distances I sometimes get NaN (Not a Number) or NA values. Also my weights don't sum to 1, and... they probably should? I'm not sure. I just need someone to clear this weighting scheme for me.

**EDIT:**
I've debugged above code, since it multiplied by weight too late (therefore not eliminating distance 0 and causing NaNs). I've also changed it to harmonic series weights, not using distance (so first neighbour has weight 1, second 1/2, third 1/3 etc.). I still don't know exactly how it works and what other weights may be.

```
inverted <- function(vals)
{
  weights <- 1 / seq(length(vals))

  res <- weighted.mean(vals, weights)
  res
}
```

Comment: Do you have any 0 values in `distances`? `NaN`s typically arise when dividing by 0

Comment: Well, I've found out that I did it wrong, I multiplied too late! I've edited my question.